# Test and Test-And-Set implementation of Spinlock

Tags: c++, memory-barriers

[This](https://rigtorp.se/spinlock/) is a Test and Test-And-Set implementation of Spinlock. The following is the code for `lock` method.

```
struct ttas_lock {
  ...
  void lock() {
    for (;;) {
      if (!lock_.exchange(true, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        break;
      }
      while (lock_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));   // <--- spin
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

It spins in a while loop to check if the lock has been released before acquiring it. So that it can reduce cache coherency traffic.

However, my question is:

Since it loads `lock_` with relaxed order, which doesn't sync with the release operation, i.e. `unlock` method, is it possible that it never loads a `false` value or it gets high latency before loading a `false` value?

Comment: You're mixing up plain visibility of the value of the atomic itself vs. syncs-with: creating a happens-before edge implying *other* later loads will see earlier stores from the other thread.  Even relaxed ops are visible promptly.  Yes, spinning read-only is the correct approach.

Comment: Yes, spinning read-only is the correct approach.  See also [Does cmpxchg write destination cache line on failure? If not, is it better than xchg for spinlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63008857) and further discussion in my answer on [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37241553).  Also the x86 `pause` instruction is a good idea `#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined (__i386__)`

Comment: My answer on [Why set the stop flag using \`memory\_order\_seq\_cst\`, if you check it with \`memory\_order\_relaxed\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70581645) is focused on whether or not `relaxed` can lead to high latency or indefinite delays; no, it can't, in any normal C++ implementation that compiles to asm for a CPU.  So I think it's a duplicate even though the test-case is quite different.