Can the spinlock implementation on xv6 not require __sync_synchronize?
While studying spinlocks in xv6, I encountered acquire barriers and release barriers. After researching and learning about them, my understanding is as follows:
// Acquire the lock.
// Loops (spins) until the lock is acquired.
void
acquire(struct spinlock *lk)
{
  push_off(); // disable interrupts to avoid deadlock.
  if(holding(lk))
    panic("acquire");

  // On RISC-V, sync_lock_test_and_set turns into an atomic swap:
  //   a5 = 1
  //   s1 = &lk->locked
  //   amoswap.w.aq a5, a5, (s1)
  while(__sync_lock_test_and_set(&lk->locked, 1) != 0)
    ;

  // Tell the C compiler and the processor to not move loads or stores
  // past this point, to ensure that the critical section's memory
  // references happen strictly after the lock is acquired.
  // On RISC-V, this emits a fence instruction.
  __sync_synchronize();

  // Record info about lock acquisition for holding() and debugging.
  lk->cpu = mycpu();
}

// Release the lock.
void
release(struct spinlock *lk)
{
  if(!holding(lk))
    panic("release");

  lk->cpu = 0;

  // Tell the C compiler and the CPU to not move loads or stores
  // past this point, to ensure that all the stores in the critical
  // section are visible to other CPUs before the lock is released,
  // and that loads in the critical section occur strictly before
  // the lock is released.
  // On RISC-V, this emits a fence instruction.
  __sync_synchronize();

  // Release the lock, equivalent to lk->locked = 0.
  // This code doesn't use a C assignment, since the C standard
  // implies that an assignment might be implemented with
  // multiple store instructions.
  // On RISC-V, sync_lock_release turns into an atomic swap:
  //   s1 = &lk->locked
  //   amoswap.w zero, zero, (s1)
  __sync_lock_release(&lk->locked);

  pop_off();
}

After reviewing code comments and some additional resources, I believe that:
__sync_lock_test_and_set(&lk->locked, 1) is equivalent to an atomic operation plus an acquire barrier.
__sync_synchronize is equivalent to a full barrier (full fence).
__sync_lock_release(&lk->locked) is equivalent to a release barrier plus an atomic operation.
1.An acquire barrier is a combination of a load-load barrier and a load-store barrier. It ensures that all load operations before the barrier occur before any load and store operations after the barrier (which can be understood as the critical section). In other words, it guarantees that operations in the critical section happen after the lock is acquired.
2.A release barrier is a combination of a load-store barrier and a store-store barrier. It ensures that all load and store operations in the critical section occur before the lock is released.
3.These two barriers create a synchronization relationship. This means that the operations performed by one thread in the critical section become immediately visible to the next thread that acquires the lock, maintaining a synchronization relationship.
Is this understanding correct? Are there any aspects I should clarify or expand upon?
Back to the title, I would like to ask if __sync_synchronize can be removed from the xv6 spinlock implementation?

Only tag C++ and C when you have a question about the interaction between the two (very different) languages.

The fence instruction is relevant on some CPU architectures not on others. The compiler will know and not emit a fence instruction if it is not needed.

@Pepijn Kramer It should be impossible for the compiler to predict whether there is an obstacle in a place. The reason why the c++ tag is added here is because when I searched for acquire-release information, most of the information I searched was about c++. If it doesn't comply with community rules, I've deleted it. Based on my understanding of the get-release model, I don't think a stronger complete barrier is needed here, so I have questions and want to make sure.

@zcqzwy_cs - You yourself write "Tell the C compiler and the processor", and that is what Pepijn refers to. On CPUs that never reorders anything, no hardware instruction is needed, so then it is only a compiler hint.

@BoP This is what I want to say __sync_lock_test_and_set and __sync_lock_release can do the same thing as __sync_synchronize, except that __sync_synchronize has a stronger barrier effect, that is, the effect of preventing reordering is stronger. It is equivalent to a full fence . __sync_lock_test_and_set is equivalent to an acquire fence, and __sync_lock_release is equivalent to a release fence. Therefore, I think that for a spinlock, an acquire fence and a release fence are enough, instead of 2 __sync_synchronize(full fence)

Seems like originally they wanted to be extra careful as they were only using xchg() so they introduced __sync_synchronize(), but later on the xchg() was replaced with __sync_lock_test_and_set() and __sync_synchronize survived. If what you are saying is correct (I'm not familiar with these intrinsics) you may be right that it's unneeded.

@MarcoBonelli Thank you for your answer. Your answer should be correct because I have reviewed the following information and think you are correct. They should implement this spin lock with a strict mentality. 1.https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_spinlock.implementation 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383363/is-my-spin-lock-implementation-correct-and-optimal 3.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217268/performance-pthread-spinlock-t-is-2x-better-than-my-own-implementation-with-lock
