# Can the read operations in `compare_exchange_strong` in different two thread read the same value?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, atomic

[atomics.types.operations] p23 says:

> bool compare_exchange_weak(T& expected, T desired, memory_order success, memory_order failure) noexcept;
>
> Effects: Retrieves the value in expected.
> It then atomically compares the value representation of the value pointed to by this for equality with that previously retrieved from expected, and if true, replaces the value pointed to by this with that in desired.
> If and only if the comparison is true, memory is affected according to the value of success, and if the comparison is false, memory is affected according to the value of failure.
> When only one memory_order argument is supplied, the value of success is order, and the value of failure is order except that a value of memory_order​::​acq_rel shall be replaced by the value memory_order​::​acquire and a value of memory_order​::​release shall be replaced by the value memory_order​::​relaxed.
> If and only if the comparison is false then, after the atomic operation, the value in expected is replaced by the value pointed to by this during the atomic comparison. If the operation returns true, these operations are atomic read-modify-write operations ([intro.multithread]) on the memory pointed to by this. Otherwise, these operations are atomic load operations on that memory.

Consider this example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
struct SpinLock{
    std::atomic<bool> atomic_;
    void lock(){
       bool expected = false;
       while (!atomic_.compare_exchange_strong(expected,true,std::memory_order_release,std::memory_order_relaxed)){

       }
    }
    void unlock(){
        atomic_.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
int main(){
    SpinLock spin{false};
    auto t1 = std::thread([&](){
        spin.lock();
        spin.unlock();
    });
    auto t2 = std::thread([&](){
        spin.lock();
        spin.unlock();
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

In this example, `spin` is initialized with the value `false`, So, can the comparison in the two threads both read this initial value `false` and compare equally with the expected value `false`? IMO, the formal wording in the standard does not forbid this possible. If they cannot, where is the relevant wording specify that this is impossible?

Comment: @PeterCordes *But if the comparison succeeds, only one CAS_strong can actually complete, the other one will have to retry because it's not CAS_weak*, the issue is it seems to there is no wording says only one `compare_and_exchange_strong` can be complete, the current wording only says they compare equally, then replace *this*.

Comment: My answer has a section that focuses more on this case, since I realized it was the thing you were concerned about.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're concerned that two `CAS_strong` operations could both actually succeed at the comparison and both take the lock.  That can't happen because according to [[atomics.ref.ops] #19](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.ref.ops#19), any `compare_exchange` is an atomic RMW operation when it succeeds:

> If the operation returns `true`, these operations are atomic read-modify-write operations on the value referenced by `*ptr`.
> Otherwise, these operations are atomic load operations on that memory.

[[atomics.order] #10](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#order-10) applies:

> Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.

This is what serializes atomic RMWs on a single object across threads, the same rule that means 1000 `.fetch_add(1)` operations increase the value by a total of 1000, not losing counts.  (It's a common misconception that the "last value" guarantee is useful beyond that, like giving lower inter-thread latency or something.  It doesn't.)

If two threads loaded the same value, then both stored a value based on the one they loaded, the second store would not be based on "last value (in the mod order) written before the write" part of the RMW, because the other thread just stored a value which precedes this store in the modification order.  So it would be based on a load that was older in the modification order, violating that rule.  This rule is what guarantees atomicity of RMWs.

---

**But the answer to your title question is "yes", as long as at least one of the `CAS_strong` operations has an `expected` that doesn't match the value loaded.**

On CAS failure, it's formally just a load, not an RMW storing back the existing value (although [in practice on x86 that's what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008857/does-cmpxchg-write-destination-cache-line-on-failure-if-not-is-it-better-than)), so the "latest value" wording for atomic RMWs doesn't forbid two CAS_strong operations from returning `false` based on seeing the same value in the modification-order of the object.

It can even happen on real hardware, at least on [LL/SC machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) where CAS_strong is just a loop around load-linked / store-conditional.

I think LL can produce a value without yet having exclusive ownership of the cache line.  Or even if it does require exclusive ownership before the load even happens, it could lose ownership before the SC.  Or since the compare is false, the SC won't even be reached.

(If the compare succeeds, but the core lost the cache line before reaching the store-conditional, CAS_strong will retry.  CAS_weak will return false, a "spurious" failure.)

I don't think LL requires *exclusive* ownership.  SC does before it can actually commit, so its success/failure depends on gaining exclusive ownership.  But knowing that no other thread modified the value between our LL and our SC just depends on not having the cache line *invalidated*.  Being in shared state for some of the time is I think ok, although that does let other cores read it between our load and our store.  So effectively the LL reads the line at the point we invalidate other copies (when we gain exclusive ownership), if we want to talk about an order of loads/stores on this object by all cores where nothing came between the load/store parts of this atomic RMW.

Comment: *Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.* I think this wording just specifies that a read-modify-write operation cannot read the value it writes. This wording didn't forbid two operations can read the same value in the modification order of the atomic object.

Comment: From the implementation perspective, I know the instructions corresponding to `CAS` and `fetch_x` are preceded by `lock`, which only permits one `CPU` to execute the instructions at the same time. However, I didn't find the relevant wording in the standard that says something conceptually about this, this is why the question is tagged with `language-lawyer`.

Comment: @xmh0511: If that happened, they wouldn't be **atomic** RMWs.  There must be some phrasing in the standard that specifies they're atomic, but I'm not sure how detailed they get about it.  Regardless, the relevant guarantee is the same one that means atomic increments don't lose counts.  If I find something, I'll update my answer.  If you just wanted to know about that, `fetch_add` would have been a simpler example, since its always an atomic RWM, vs. CAS_strong being formally only a read on CAS failure.  (And in practice on LL/SC machines, which unlike x86 don't have a single instruction RMW.)

Comment: I indeed don't find that rule. So, I'm looking forward to there is an answer that can cite the formal rule that can interpret this question

Comment: @xmh0511: Upon more careful reading, the rule I quoted *is* the one that guarantees atomicity for atomic RMWs, like I was originally thinking.  If two threads loaded the same value, then both stored a value based on the one they loaded, the second store would not be based on "last value (in the mod order) written **before the write associated with the RMW op**".  Instead it would be based on a load that was older in the modification order, violating that rule.

Comment: I tried to understand what you are saying. Assume the modification order first has the modification `M0` whose value is the initial value `false`, then, assume two `CAS` operations both read `M0`, since the modification produced by the two operations (A and B) in the modification order is ordered(i.e. either `MA` follows `MB` in the order, or `MB` follows `MA` in the order), we say the one in the second is `MX`,  then we can get the modification order of the atomic object `M0(false) -> MX(true)`, in this modification order, the operation that does not produce `MX`...

Comment: ...reads the value `M0` that is not the last value in the modification, hence such two operations cannot happen concurrently. Is my understanding of your answer right?

Comment: @xmh0511: yes.  I found it easier to think through basically the same example with `fetch_add` in mind, since the "lost count" example of a non-atomic increment is already familiar.  But CAS operations where the compare succeeds follow the same rules, and the key point is that if `MB` committed after `MA` in the mod order, then its load needs to have seen `MA`.

Comment: @JanSchultke  Thanks for the edit.  I'd omitted that quote about when CAS is an atomic RMW since the question quoted that part, but having it in the answer is probably better.

Comment: Your answers are good. I just have two issues here: 1. Where is the rule that says RMW is a modification in the modification order? 2. If we stand at the perspective of the reading in two RMW operations, before their write, they do indeed read the last value in the modification(that is the initial value), which is written before their write. Maybe the wording will be clearer if it is changed: read-modify-write operation on `M` shall always read the value from a side effect `X` that immediately precedes the read-modify-write operation in the modification order of `M`.

Comment: @xmh0511 The wording for `compare_exchange` says that the value of the object gets replaced (exactly like `.store()`). A better question regarding 1. is "Why would this not count as a modification?" I think the intent of the wording is overall fairly clear. You can contribute to https://github.com/cplusplus/draft if you feel like there is room for improvement though.

Comment: @xmh0511: 1. http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#4 - "**All** modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order, called the modification order of M." (my emphasis).  2. That could work as well, but IDK if it's any clearer than the current wording.  The current wording avoids treating the atomic RMW as a single operation, because it's not when we consider operations on *other* objects: [For purposes of ordering, is atomic read-modify-write one operation or two?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65568185)

Comment: @xmh0511: (1) is not stated as an explicit rule, it's just the common meaning of the English word "modification".  In context it's clear that they mean something that changes the value of an object.  Obviously a RMW does that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Further discussion can be done here https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/423