# Are there any thread safety issues in volatile reading value written with Interlocked.Exchange in this code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free, interlocked

```
class TaskTracker
{
    private volatile ConcurrentBag<Task> _bag = new();
    
    public async Task WaitAllAvailableAsync()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(Interlocked.Exchange(ref _bag, new()));
    }

    public void AddTask(Task toWait)
    {
        // should guarantee that the Task will be awaited on at least one WaitAllAvailableAsync call
        ConcurrentBag<Task> oldBag, bag = _bag;
        do
        {
            bag.Add(toWait);
            oldBag = bag;
        } while ((bag = _bag) != oldBag);
    }
}
```

This class allows its user to add tasks to the internal list. When the `WaitAllAvailableAsync` is called, all currently added tasks are removed from the list and awaited. This may be used as a barrier mechanism to wait for all already started incoming requests to complete (without blocking adding newer requests). Both methods are thread safe and can be used from any number of threads. `WaitAllAvailableAsync` is called on a timer.

I'm not sure about the guarantees applied to this line:

```
} while ((bag = _bag) != oldBag);
```

Image that `Interlocked.Exchange(` have already executed at this point and another instance of bag was written. Does volatile read of `_bag` really guarantees seeing the new value? Would `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _bag, null, null)` provide better guarantees?

I saw many different opinions about the difference between Interlocked and volatile non-caching guarantees. Some people say that volaile only prevents reordering, others say that is also ensures reading somewhat fresh value but it can be stale by a few milli/nanoseconds. For the code above reading any stale value can lead to that the task will be added to an already discarded `_bag` instance and thus the task will never be awaited. I'm not sure whom to believe so I decided to ask here.

So are there any thread-safety issues here? Is there any scenario when added task will not be awaited inside `WaitAllAvailableAsync` call at least once (assuming endless running)?

I know that this code may be rewritten without volatile by using ConcurrentQueue but here I'm trying to understand specifically the behavior of the volatile read in this example.

Comment: What on earth does this even do?

Comment: You're already using a thread safe collection, why do you need to atomically swap it?

Comment: `while ((bag = _bag) != oldBag)` is not thread-safe, use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` instead.

Comment: @Charlieface, please provide a detailed answer if you think that `volatile` is not enough in this case

Comment: @Charlieface I think that the question is about a specific piece of code. It's not about the difference between the `Interlocked` and `volatile` in general. The three questions linked as duplicates can be found in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77808420/timeline).

Comment: @Joshua I added more details to the question including the code description

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any scenario when added task will not be awaited inside `WaitAllAvailableAsync` call at least once (assuming endless running)?

In my opinion, no, there is no scenario where an added task will not be awaited by the `WaitAllAvailableAsync` at least once. The code as is should perform correctly its intended purpose, on all systems that are currently (.NET 8) supported by the .NET runtime.

My understanding is that *in practice* (on all currently supported systems) reading a `volatile` field returns a value equally fresh with reading the same field with `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _field, null, null)`. Which should return a value fresh enough to satisfy the requirements for the correctness of the code in the question. I would be very surprised if it was proven experimentally that a system exists where the code in the question fails to work correctly.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed explanation? I'm not sure whether `Volatile.Read` will always read fresh value of `_bag`, written with `Interlocked.Exchange`. If it reads a stale value, it's totally possible that the loop check will think that `_bag` was not changed when in reality it was.

Comment: @Vlad the `Volatile.Read` doesn't read stale values. It reads whatever is in the memory at the moment, with a memory barrier that prevents reordering of instructions. Writing a complete explanation would be quite tedious ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c/77423332#77423332)). Honestly code like this is a huge maintenance burden. Reasoning about its correctness is hard and error-prone. Most likely there are better ways to do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: According to other answers on similar topics, `Volatile.Read` only prevents reordering and optimizations (including caching), but doesn't guarantee any "freshness". There are different opinions on whether `Interlocked.Read/CompareExchange` have stronger guarantees in this sense. This is why I've been not sure about this snippet and asked here. Your answer is the same as my opinion but I still don't have proofs.

Comment: @Vlad yep, there is tons of uncertainty [and confusion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67330 "Confusion regarding Volatile.Read guarantees, and example in the volatile docs") about what the `volatile` does. Which is a good indication that you shouldn't have code like this in your codebase. The cost of the research far outweighs the potential benefits.

Comment: `Interlocked.CompareExchange` will (at least on x86-64) wait until it has exclusive ownership of the cache line before even reading a value from L1d cache.  (That might not be the case on ARMv8.0 for the failure side of a CAS).  That usually doesn't matter, and is also more a matter of making this thread wait so the read just happens later, instead of "reaching farther" to take a fresher value at the same time.

Comment: The reason atomic RMWs need to make guarantees about "latest value" is so they're linearizable, so for example atomic CAS and increments can work properly (not stepping on each other).  ([Can the read operations in \`compare\_exchange\_strong\` in different two thread read the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77126363) no, if both CAS's succeed.).  So concerns about values not being "fresh" are usually worrying about the wrong thing for read-only accesses, but I'd still be uncomfortable about saying "equal freshness" as a general statement.

Comment: It's more like, worry about ordering not absolute timing / "latest value", and understand how acquire / release semantics work: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/  (Which IIRC is what you get with C# `volatile`.) @Vlad

Answer (score 1):

This code cannot and does not work. It has the appearance of working if only one thread can call `WaitAllAvailableAsync()`, but ...

```
Thread 1                                       Thread 2
                                               bag = _bag;
rax = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _bag, new())
                                               bag.Add(toWait);                                            

Task.WhenAll(rax)                              while ((bag = _bag) != oldBag)
                                               bag.Add(toWait);

//... much later

Task.WhenAll(Interlocked.Exchange(ref _bag, new()))
```

It seems harmless to await a task twice but it isn't if the task threw an exception.

To do this kind of thing we need to use `Interlocked.Exchange` correctly on both sides. I'm going to run my mouth off here.

```
class TaskTracker {
    private class TaskListNode : IEnumerable<Task> {
        public static readonly TaskListNode EndOfList = new TaskListNode(null);

        private TaskListNode next;
        private Task<T> task;
        public TaskListNode(Task t) { task = t; }
        public SetListHead(ref TaskListNode head) {
            // Interlocked here
            do {
                next = head;
            } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(head, this, next) != next);
        }
        public IEnumerator<Task> GetEnumerator() => new Enumerator(this); }
        private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<Task>() {
            private TaskListNode first;
            private TaskListNode next;
            public Task Current { get; private set; }
            public Enumerator(TaskListNode start) { next = first = start; }
            public void Reset() { next = first; }
            public bool MoveNext() {
                if (next == EndOfList || next is null) return false;
                current = next.task;
                next = next.next;
            }
            public void Dispose() {}
        }
    }

    private TaskListNode head = TaskListNode.EndOfList;

    public Task WaitAllAvailableAsync()
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(Interlocked.Exchange(ref head, TaskListNode.EndOfList));
    }

    public void AddTask(Task toWait)
    {
        new TaskListNode(toWait).SetListHead(ref head);
    }
```

The `Interlocked.Exchange()` call was right. Not doing another `Interlocked` call in `AddTask()` was not. I ended up having to swap the datastructure out to get something I could find an `Interlocked` method for that was actually useful. The single linked list works well here.

Comment: Based on the in-code comment in the question, the OP wants to `await` each task at least once, not exactly once. Also instead of writing your own custom immutable stack (linked list), you could just use the built-in [`ImmutableStack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablestack-1) class, and update it atomically with the [`ImmutableInterlocked.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update) method.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I think OP hasn't realized that awaiting tasks twice is wrong. I don't see the right signature on any overload of ImmutableInterlocked.Update to extend the stack without copying it.

Comment: It's the `ImmutableInterlocked.Update<T>(T, Func<T,T>)` overload. It can be used like this: `ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _stack, x => x.Push(toWait));`. The `_stack` is replaced atomically with a new stack that contains all the elements of the old stack plus the new element. Why is it wrong to `await` a task twice?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: It's a large scope transform to handle exceptions being thrown twice instead of once, and requires a twisted mind to come up with it, and the rules for when it is safe are not what one would expect.

Comment: We don't know exactly what the OP wants to do. They might intend to ignore all exceptions using a `try` block with an empty `catch`. Awaiting a `Task` twice is not wrong in general, and most likely the OP is not going to be more specific because their question is focused on a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with some "interlocked immutable state" approaches recently. Here's the current version of my helpers:

```
internal static class InterlockedState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a state transition from one state to another.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the state; this is generally an immutable type. Strongly consider using a record class.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="state">The location of the state.</param>
    /// <param name="transformation">The transformation to apply to the state. This may be invoked any number of times and should be a pure function.</param>
    /// <param name="oldState">The old state.</param>
    /// <returns>The new state.</returns>
    public static T Transform<T>(ref T state, Func<T, T> transformation, out T oldState)
        where T : class?
    {
        _ = transformation ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transformation));

        while (true)
        {
            oldState = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, default!, default!);
            var newState = transformation(oldState);
            if (ReferenceEquals(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state!, newState, oldState), oldState))
                return newState;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the current state. Note that the state may have changed by the time this method returns.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the state; this is generally an immutable type. Strongly consider using a record class.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="state">The location of the state.</param>
    /// <returns>The current state.</returns>
    public static T Read<T>(ref T state)
        where T : class? =>
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, default!, default!);
}
```

They can be used like this:

```
class TaskTracker
{
    private ImmutableHashSet<Task> _bag = ImmutableHashSet<Task>.Empty;

    public Task WaitAllAvailableAsync()
    {
        InterlockedState.Transform(ref _bag, _ => ImmutableHashSet<Task>.Empty, out var oldBag);
        return Task.WhenAll(oldBag);
    }

    public void AddTask(Task toWait)
    {
        InterlockedState.Transform(ref _bag, bag => bag.Add(toWait), out _);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen you could compare your implementation with [Microsoft's implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableInterlocked.cs#L34) (`ImmutableInterlocked.Update`).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Yes, I've seen that one. I prefer returning the new and old state rather than just a bool.

Comment: The `oldState = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, default!, default!);` might make the operation more heavy than it needs to be. In the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488734/should-interlocked-compareexchange-also-a-volatile-variable/66492349#66492349), Peter Cordes questions if even a volatile read is necessary.

Comment: When it comes to memory models, ordering, and barrier acquisition, I have two rules of thumb: 1) Use the same level of abstraction for all access (in this case, I use ICE for both updates and reads), and 2) I am not smart enough to use volatile.